# How can a variable be a bool and an int at the same time?

Tags: python, types, isinstance

I am currently working on understanding types and how to check for them. I'm now stuck on this:

```
input_variable = True

print(type(input_variable))

print(isinstance(input_variable, bool))
print(isinstance(input_variable, int))
print(isinstance(input_variable, str))
print(isinstance(input_variable, float))
```

This outputs:

```
<class 'bool'>

True
True
False
False
```

I'm expecting the variable to be a bool, which is confirmed by the first `type()` statement. I'm trying to understand why both the `isinstance()` checks for bool and int return true. So I tried to cast my original variable to an int with

```
int(input_variable)
```

which gives me 1. I sort of understand this with True = 1 and False = 0, but I'm still confused as to why I don't have to explicitly cast the variable to an int to have `isinstance()` recognize it as such.

Comment: In Python, bool is a subtype of int.

Comment: You're going to get a kick out of this when you get to abstract classes. You can retroactively insert a parent type into a class.

Comment: Worth reading [PEP 285 - Adding a bool type](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0285/)

Comment: @buran Good read. I wonder how many reviewers today would rethink their answer to #4, and #6 also seems like a poor decision (choosing a public facing interface because it simplifies the implementation?), though one that backwards compatibility forced at the time.

Comment: Because `issubclass(book, int)` and `isinstance(x, Klass)` checks if `x` has `Klass` anywhere in its method resolution order